# How to set up Maven to override a settings file for another when running a test?

Tags: java, maven-2, profiling, settings

See the following Maven generated project

```
target
    classes
    test-classes
src
    main
        java
        scripts
        resources
            datasource-settings.xml
    test
        java
        resources
            datasource-settings.xml
```

I would like, **when running a test**, to use the settings found in test/resources/datasource-settings.xml instead of main/resources/datasource-settings.xml. Is it possible ? If so, what should i do to get my goal ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resources placed in `${basedir}/src/test/resources` (the default location) will be automatically added to the class path set up by Maven for your unit tests and take precedence over resources placed in `${basedir}/src/main/resources`. So what you want to do is actually just the default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't modified the resource settings in your POM, the test resources should show up in your classpath first, so a test should find that file before the main one without you needing to do anything extra. What sort of behavior are you seeing?

Comment: @Jeff Storey A Seam-gem generated project uses a similar behavior as shown in my question. So i want to get the same behavior when running a Maven project. I will try it tomorrow. Thank you!