# How to make maven override properties files from src/main/resources to the ones from src/test/resources when running tests?

Tags: maven, testing, properties, overriding

I'm trying to make maven override properties files from src/main/resources to the ones from src/test/resources when running tests. Unfortunatelly, when I run a test I get properties from main/resources directory.

I've got one global build

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
```

and another for separate profiles. For development:
    development
            
                true
                
                    envtype
                    dev

```
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources-dev</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>${basedir}/src/test/resources-dev</directory>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>
        </build>
```

As for tests, properties reside in src/test/resources. As for main, they belong to the folder with the suffix of the profile, for example /src/test/resources-dev. May it be an issue? I though maven will override any files by default.

Comment: Resources placed in `src/test/resources` should take precedence over resources in `src/main/resources` because they are added to the classpath first (and so should be discovered first). This is the default behaviour - see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285921/how-to-set-up-maven-to-override-a-settings-file-for-another-when-running-a-test). You've explicitly redefined this in your pom config - which may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: You mean the order of specifying resources in build tag matters? I've swaped it but still it doesn't work.